# unable login solaris box

Tags: security, solaris

There is problem on my Solaris 10 box.

It's not possible to access directly to the box, but via `ssh` from another box after 3 wrong entries of username/password to box then login prompt changes, at this point, I can access to box by entering its own password.

Here is when I  tried to login with correct password.

```
# ssh 10.0.70.11
Authorized use only, activities logged.
Password:
Last login: Thu May  2 15:01:05 2013 from 10.0.70.8
Sun Microsystems Inc.   SunOS 5.10      Generic January 2005 >>>>> it seems that is  connected.
Connection to 10.0.70.11 closed.  >>>>>> then kicked off
```

Here is the scenario that I mentioned.

```
#ssh 10.0.70.11
Authorized use only, activities logged.
Password:               >>>>>  tried wrong password
Password:               >>>>> tried wrong password
Password:               >>>>> tried wrong password lastly
root@10.0.70.11's password:
Last login: Thu May  2 16:41:49 2013 from 10.0.70.8
Sun Microsystems Inc.   SunOS 5.10      Generic January 2005
Sun Microsystems Inc.   SunOS 5.10      Generic January 2005
#
```

Does anyone has any information/feedback about this ?

Answer (score 2):

1. When you login as `root`, check system logs ( `/var/adm/messages`, `who`, `last`, `dmesg`, etc) to see if you see any errors relating to SSH configuration.
2. Check your /etc/pam.conf file.  Are you using multiple authentication schemes?  That login prompt changing suggests that there may be multiple auth entries for SSH in PAM.
3. Use `-v` with ssh to see some verbose logging of the ssh session.  Look for errors.
4. Does SSH as another user besides root work?  If so, look at the output of `ssh -v` for errors related to the permissions of ssh keys, or the .ssh directory, etc.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like your password may have been locked. While you're logged in as root, try `passwd -u <useraccount>`. Or, `passwd -d <useraccount>` to delete the password for the user. Here is the [man page](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19082-01/819-2239/passwd-1/index.html) for passwd.